# FCM Token is generated on my device but not generated on other devices

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a really weird issue,

I have the following flutter code to generate FCM Token for the user upon sign up so I can send them push notification from my backend:

```
 String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  if (fcmToken != null) {
    log("FCM Token is not null with value = $fcmToken");
    UserAPIService.refreshUserFCMToken(fcmToken);
  } else {
    log("FCM Token is null"); //Other users weirdly keep getting null
  }
```

This code works on my Android device. But doesn't work on other Android Device users of my app.

However, I am signing my users in with a custom token generated from my `nodejs` backend.

Here is how I generate the custom token in `nodejs`

```
let firebaseCustomToken = await firebase.auth().createCustomToken(apiKey);
```

And then on the flutter side I have this code:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCustomToken(firebaseCustomToken/*This is sent from the backend immediately after sign up before communicating with firebase*/)
        .then((userCredentials)async {

  String? fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
  if (fcmToken != null) {
    log("FCM Token is not null with value = $fcmToken");
    UserAPIService.refreshUserFCMToken(fcmToken);
  } else {
    log("FCM Token is null"); //Other users weirdly keep getting null
  }

}
```

Please note that I have submitted my release and debug keys already to firebase.

What could be wrong, I can't seem to figure out?

Comment: What other device? Android/ios/web? What is the debug report?

Comment: What device are you using? Android or iOS did you check for permissions? You can read more about it here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/permissions

Comment: Android to be specific

Comment: Do you have different tokens for each user? Did you check if the user has permission do receive notifications on the device. Are the other users on prod or dev build?